# jQuery Mobile: changepage to another page without showing Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The situation is as follows:

Given 3 Pages: Pag_A, Pag_B and Pag_C.

User starts on "Pag_A", Pag_A changes to "Pag_B", Pag_B evaluates some coditions which results in a jump to "Pag_C".

I have tried all JQuery Events and none of them satisfied me. The closest approach is using Pag_B's 'pagebeforecreate' event as follows:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#Pag_B', function(e){
if (someCondition==true){
    $.mobile.changePage('#Pag_C');
    }
});
```

It works well, except that Pag_B is shown to the user.....How can I have a smooth transition without showing Pag_B???

I have tried to insert:  (Before $.mobile.changePage('#Pag_C');)

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
('Pag_B').remove();
```

All of them are useless....

I have tried too:

```
'pagebeforecreate'
'pagebeforeshow'
'pagebeforecreate'
'pagecreate'
```

All of them beahave in the same way....ie, Page_B is horribly displayed...

Comment: How about evaluating your conditions when whatever happens that gets the user to `Page_B`? If you get to `Page_B` by clicking something, add the evaluation code to a click event handler for that button (or whatever). That way you don't have to muck around in jQM code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the api, have you tried this?

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/

Comment: Yes, I tested after you posted, the beavour is the same....than using 'pagebeforecreate'

Comment: So your logic is if this show C instead of B else show B? Shouldn't you do this on page A before calling show B from A?

Comment: That's true pal, the redirection logic is on Page_B, not on Page_A....If no other solution is found, I should rethink all over....Thanks....I'll waitl until someone give me a flash...

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/GPUay/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){  
    var dummy = false;

    var to = data.toPage,
        from = data.options.fromPage;

    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
        if (from) from = '#' + from.attr('id');

        if (from === '#index' && to === '#second' && dummy === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();            
            $.mobile.changePage( "#third");
        }
    }
});
```

Just play with a dummy variable, switch it from true to false to see how to use this solution.

Comment: Just curious, why is this best and what's the alternative?

Comment: It doesn't work, it should go straight to Third, but it goes to Second, I dont see the punch......

Comment: Have you even tried to test this example? What will happen if dummy is set to true and what will happen if dummy is set to false.